# Probability of drawing cards from one deck

Tags: probability

When you draw 8 cards from a 52 card deck, what is the probability that all 8 of those cards are of different number(value)? What is the probability that in those 8 cards drawn, there is only one pair( meaning that in total there are 7 different values of cards)?

Comment: How did you come to the problem? What are your thoughts on it?

Comment: It’s relative to a poker game that our family plays. I had (52*48*44...*24) over 52p8 for the 8 different card. But I think we have to multiply that by something which I am not sure what and how.

Comment: Please edit your post to add your thoughts/work on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give a complete answer to the following general problem. Assume a deck of cards with $m$ suits, each suit consisting of $n$ flavors (values). In the standard deck $m=4, n=13$.

Let choose randomly $k$ cards $0\le k\le mn$ and represent the result of the draw as the following vector:
$$
\mathbf{r}=(r_0,r_1,\dots, r_m),\quad r_i\ge0,
$$ 
where the number $r_i, i=1\dots m$ stays for the number of $i$-tuples of a flavor, whereas 
$$
r_0=n-\sum_{i=1}^m r_i.
$$ 
Observe that by the definition $\sum_{i=0}^m r_i=n, \sum_{i=0}^m i r_i=k$.

Though the above definition may sound complicated, in reality it is not. See the solution of your particular problem below.

In the terms of the definition a general question can be formulated as: "how many combinations do exist for given $\mathbf{r}$? (There are 15 possible vectors $\mathbf{r}$ for the set of 8 cards drawn from the standard deck).

The answer to the above question appears to be very simple. The number of all unordered $k$-sets with the given vector ${\mathbf r}$ is:
$$
N_{\mathbf r}=\binom{\sum_i r_i}{r_0,r_1,\dots,r_m}\prod_{i=0}^m\binom mi^{r_i}
\equiv[\mathbf r](\mathbf{P}_m)^\mathbf{r},
$$
where $[\mathbf r]$ and $\mathbf{P}_m$ are, respectively, the shortcuts for the multinomial and the $m$-th Pascal triangle row:
$$
\left(\binom m0,\binom m1,\dots,\binom mm\right),
$$
and the operation $\mathbf{a}^{\mathbf b}$ for two vectors of equal size is defined as:
$$
\mathbf{a}^{\mathbf b}\equiv\prod_i a_i^{b_i}.
$$

Let us now apply this machinery to your problem: $\mathbf{r}_1=(5,8,0,0,0)$, $\mathbf{r}_2=(6,6,1,0,0)$:

$$
N_1=\binom{13}{5,8,0,0,0}\binom41^8=84344832,\quad N_2=\binom{13}{6,6,1,0,0}\binom41^6\binom42^1=295206912.
$$

Dividing the results by the overall number of unordered combinations $N=\binom{52}8$ one obtains the corresponding probabilities:

$$
p_1\approx0.11208,\quad p_2\approx0.39228.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Observing your comment from above, you are on the right track.  Notice that if we arrange this in terms of "filling in slots" we can ask how many ways can we select the first card?  This will obviously be 52.  For filling in the second card, we have to remove our selected card and all other cards that have the same face value, hence there will be 48 choices for the second card.  Continuing on like this you will obtain $52\cdot 48\cdot 44\cdot 40\cdot 36\cdot 32\cdot 28\cdot 24$, as you implied in your comment.

There is however one major problem with this, and this is the fact that this multiplication counts the number of permutations of 8-card hands with different face values.  In other words, this quantity not only counts the number of distinct 8-card hands but also all of the different ways to shuffle the same 8 cards.  Because $n!$ is the number of ways to shuffle $n$ items, the correct way to count the number of hands is given by:

$$
\text{# of 8-card hands with distinct faces} \;\; =\;\; \frac{52\cdot 48\cdot 44\cdot 40\cdot 36\cdot 32\cdot 28\cdot 24}{8!} \;\; =\;\; 84,344,832.
$$

If we compute the total number of distinct 8-card hands, which is $C_{52,8} = 752,538,150$ we can then find the probability:

$$
P(\text{8-card hand with distinct faces}) \;\; =\;\; \frac{84,344,832}{752,538,150} \;\; \approx \;\; 0.112.
$$

Comment: How was the 84,344,832 produced?

Comment: @jaysen What do you mean?  Multiply the numbers in the numerator and divide by 8!.

Comment: For the 7 distant face value question, should I use C52,7 for the denominators as well,

Comment: @jaysen Yes, $C_{52,7}$ will be the number of 7-card hands, but the number of 7-card hands with distinct face values will be $\frac{52\cdot 48\ldots 32\cdot 28}{7!}$.

Comment: I would get the same result for the whole equation by doing (52*48..*24)/P52,8

Comment: @jaysen Yes, technically you do get the same probability.  However, if you were interested in the number of possible hands there are satisfying the properties you want, then you'd have to use combinations.

Comment: I understand now thanks for the explanation